# Debug In-dialog provided python code in QGIS attribute form 'Python Init Code Configuration'

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, attribute-form

In a QGIS layers attribute form configuration I have the following *Python Init Code Configuration*:

[image]

Code in plain text:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLineEdit
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt

def atlas_punkte_init_values(dialog, layer, feature):
    #geom = feature.geometry()
    control = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit, 'str')
    print(control)
    l = dialog.findChildren(QLabel)
    print(l)
```

As one can see at first sight, this code is erroneous, because `QLabel` is not imported. By means of this, I would expect an exception somewhat like `...NameError: name 'QLabel' is not defined`, but the only thing I get is this:

[image]

Because far trickier error constellations are imaginable than a forgotten import, debugging of more extensive scripts is nearly impossible that way.

First idea is to look at python errors in the log or the python console, but thats a fail.

Do I miss a location where qualified exceptions are thrown by these scripts or is there really no chance to properly debug these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should allow macros to run in "Settings > General". QGIS cannot find the function because macros is not allowed. In this case, QGIS shows an error message dialog and gives a warning in Log Messages panel in later versions as in the image.

[image]

When using 'Python Init Code Configuration', debugging is a black hole in earlier QGIS 3 versions. But in QGIS v3.12+, "Python error" window shows the error message now.

[image]